# How are these twig variables initialized or injected

Tags: cakephp, twig, cakephp-3.0

I'm looking at `form.twig` and I see the following line near the top of the file:

```
{% set fields = Bake.filterFields(fields, schema, modelObject) %}
```

If I attempt to use the variable `schema` in another twig file (ex. `entity.twig`), it fails. Where are these variable initialized/injected?

**Edit #1**

All variables available in `entity.twig`

```
/tmp/cache/twigView/f9/f9e579e257fbf8646e4fb36344bec8b65599b3bdf9e4b72e538604521bd173e1.php (line 33)
########## DEBUG ##########
[
    (int) 0 => 'associations',
    (int) 1 => 'associationInfo',
    (int) 2 => 'primaryKey',
    (int) 3 => 'displayField',
    (int) 4 => 'table',
    (int) 5 => 'propertySchema',
    (int) 6 => 'fields',
    (int) 7 => 'validation',
    (int) 8 => 'rulesChecker',
    (int) 9 => 'behaviors',
    (int) 10 => 'connection',
    (int) 11 => 'hidden',
    (int) 12 => 'name',
    (int) 13 => 'namespace',
    (int) 14 => 'plugin',
    (int) 15 => 'pluginPath',
    (int) 16 => 'entity'
]
```

Comment: https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/twig-bake-template-variables-origin-cakephp-3-x/5092/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are created in the relevant bake task. For templates that's `\Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask`, and the variables are generated in its [**`_loadController()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.12.0/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php#L276) method.

Entities are being baked via `\Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask`, and it generates a different set of view variables, one that fits the needs of tables/entities, see the [**`getTableContext()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.12.0/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php#L129) method (shared by tables and entities), and the [**`bakeEntity()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.12.0/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php#L945) method.

You can always use [**the `getVars()` function**](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView/tree/4.3.8#functions) in your twig template to get a list of all currently set view variables:

```
{% do getVars()|debug %}
```

Comment: Just love how this framework has its own vocabulary

Comment: In `entity.twig`, using your snippet with `getVars()` gives me `Unknown "getVars" function`.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus That looks like a bug, seems like the required twig extension isn't being loaded. You may want to report that over at **https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView/issues**.

Comment: @ndm before I do this, I want to confirm that I'm using cake bake model all -t MyPlugin. In this plugin, I have entity.twig, which contains the getVars function, which is crashing with the message I provided. Does this context still warrant an issue on Github, or perhaps I missed something at my end? Maybe I'm missing something composer.json?

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus Nah it's certainly an issue on the plugins' end, either the docs are wrong by listing the function, or the plugin is wrong by not loading the extension. I've just tested it by adding `$event->getTwig()->addExtension(new Extension\View($event->getTwigView()));` in `\WyriHaximus\TwigView\Event\ExtensionsListener::construct()`, doing so `getVars()` then works fine.

Comment: So, if I need more info than is provided, I need to add ModelTask in my plugin and tweak it to output what I need? I just need to get more field metadata (ex. autoIncrement, etc)

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus Not necessarily, depending on what exactly you need to do to retrieve what you're looking for, you might be able to use a custom/extended helper, or just hook into events and work with view variables, see **https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/development.html**.

Comment: @ndm If I could gain access to `Bake.columnData(field, schema)` in `entity.twig`, that would enable me to get more metadata about the field that way. I don't seem to have access to a schema variable of type `\Cake\Database\Schema\TableSchema` for the second parameter of columnData. I think I'm going to need another slight nudge.